# How to counting the Number of Records displayed by a stored procedure with ExecuteReader to have a better control for a progress bar

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Below is my piece of code which I am using to retrieve records from a stored Procedure. I want to have the record count so as to be able to define the maximum value for my ProgressBar.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Pax].[SP_Tax_By_Coupon_Level_And_Surcharge]", cs);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesDate_From", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesDate_To", dateTimePicker2.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentType", "Tax");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgentNumCode", ag);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocNum", docn);

this.progressBar1.Value = 0;

int rows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteReader());

cs.Close();

cs.Open();


SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

this.progressBar1.Maximum = rows;


int i = 0;

while (rd.Read())
{
    this.progressBar1.Value++;

    dbgTAX.Rows.Add("");


    dbgTAX.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = rd.GetValue(0).ToString();
    dbgTAX.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = rd.GetValue(1).ToString();
    dbgTAX.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = rd.GetValue(2).ToString();

    i++;
}
```

Comment: "Please wait. Calibrating progress bar...". Is it really worth it having the stored procedure run twice just to be able to show progress? Perhaps you can write a simplified version of the proc that just returns the row count. Aside from this, what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I want to know the record count. I had search everywhere, but no answer for this. To be able to have the row count i must use ExecuteScalar but it will work only if i want to display 1 column. But here i have several Columns

Answer (score 0):

How long does it actually take? If it is less than a few seconds, don't bother with a progress bar, or just let it zap straight to 50% once Execute returns, then straight to 100% when you finish. Nobody will care.

Alternatively if it does take a long time (10 seconds upwards), if you just want the user to see "ooh, progress!" then just do this.

```
//first
progressBar1.MaxValue = 10000;


// Then in your DataReader loop
if(i % 100 == 0){
    progressBar1.Value += (progressBar1.MaxValue - progressBar1.Value)/10;
}
```

This will make the progress bar creep towards the finish line by 10% every 100 rows, but never actually reach it, so the user sees movement and knows activity is taking place. Then zap to 100% at the end.